# E-Book reader development technique

Tags: c#, angularjs, pdf, cross-platform, epub

I'm working on a web project using AngularJs and WebApi 2 to create cross platform web client.

The project should support **PDF** and **ePUB** books and I need to provide the client with rich unified book viewer for booth formats.

My thoughts was to upload both formats and convert the PDF to the ePUB format and develop or find an open source ePUB viewer for the client side UI.

**Problems**:

1. Proper C# library to convert PDF to ePUB keeping the PDF format.
2. Ideas for streaming the books with large size to the client.
3. Secure the book If download needed.

Comment: try readium-js-viewer for solving your 2 and 3 problems. :)

Comment: did u try? why you want to convert pdf to epub?

Comment: @null1941 I posted what I used to solve the Issue as answer to be clearly monitored by other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the client and did some changes, I knew that the PDF books are scanned images so I extracted it using **ITextSharp** library,About the ePUB books I used the "**[VersFx.Formats.Text.Epub](https://github.com/versfx/EpubReader)**" library form NuGet to pares the books and it was sufficient.

- About the readers I used "**[JQuery booklet plugin](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/)**" for ePUB as it is text based books, And "**[TurnJS plugin](http://www.turnjs.com/)**" for image based books "PDF" as mentioned earlier.